# Android Media Player

Tags: android, audio, media-player, state-diagram

I am attempting to play a sound using a MediaPlayer object, but I cannot seem to get it to work despite my best efforts. The sound simply refuses to play.

It's a short sound, that is supposed to be played when the screen is touched, meaning it will have to be repeated many times without too much delay. Knowing this I followed the state diagram, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html. I can't seem to see what exactly is wrong with my sequencing of method calls.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this.getContext(), R.raw.select2);
try {
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();                 
    Log.e("debug","sound played");
    }
catch(Exception e) {}
mp.stop();
```

Comment: No need of call prepare method.....In the first line it is automatically prepared and you have to start player in onPrepare listener...

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the OnPreparedListener class. It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `prepare()` on the mediaplayer, but the [create()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) call you use prepares the player automatically, this causes an `IllegalStateException` when you try to call `prepare()` again, and you are sent to your `catch()` (you would have noticed this if you handled the exception in some way, i.e. printing the stack trace).

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this.getContext(), R.raw.select2);
```

we configure the music player by setting some of its properties as shown below

```
player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext()PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
player.setOnErrorListener(this);
try {
   player.prepare();
   player.start();                 
   Log.e("debug","sound played");
}  catch(Exception e) {}
  player.stop();
```